# jQuery find when user scrolled out an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll

I have 2 `divs`:

```
<div id="div1"></div>
<div id="div2"></div>
```

I would like to add `css({'position':'relative'})` to div2 ONLY when a user scrolls the page and div1 is no longer visible on the page. When div1 is visible again, I want to remove the css rule.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Looks exactly what you're after: http://remysharp.com/2009/01/26/element-in-view-event-plugin/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is not perfect, but i've written you a quick plugin to take care of this: 
http://jsfiddle.net/m7ztR/1/

it can be used in two ways:

**it gives you a new selector**
`console.log( $( "#elem" ).is( ":inView" )? "visible":"invisible" );`

you can also use this to get all visible elements, e.g. 
`console.log( $( "p:inView" ).get() );`

**and something like an event-listener**
$( "#watchThisElement" ).visibilityChange( function( visible ){
    if( visible ){
      // do this ... 
    }
    else{
      // do that ... 
    }
} );

note: this is not complete for a bunch of reasons!!

1. it only handles vertical scrolling
2. it does not handle iframes (and might screw up horribly with nested scrolling)
3. there is no unbind
4. it might get slow if you watch a lot of elements
5. does not take window resizing into account

it's something i quickly hacked up from similar code i had sitting around.

if the jsfiddle link ever dies, here's the actual code and markup:

**html:**

```
<div id="status">look at my background color!</div>

<div id="above">lots of space above ... </div>
<div id="trackMe">i'm being tracked!</div>
<div id="below">lots of space below ... </div>
```

**css:**

```
#status{
    position: fixed; 
    right: 0; 
    top: 0; 
    background-color: red; 
}

#above, #below{
    height: 800px; 
    background-color: yellow; 
}
```

**javascript:**

```
/**
 * jquery (in)visibility plugin ... 
 */
(function( $ ){
    var w = $( window ); 

    // add a custom ":inView" selector
    $.expr[':'].inView = function(obj){
        var $this = $(obj);
        var relY = $this.offset().top - w.scrollTop(); 
        return relY >= 0 && relY <= w.height(); 
    }; 

    $.fn.visibilityChange = function( fun ) {  
        return this.each(function() {
            var elem = $(this);
            var pVisible = elem.is( ":inView" ); 
            $( document ).scroll( function( e ){
                if( pVisible != elem.is( ":inView" ) ){
                    pVisible = !pVisible; 
                    fun( pVisible ); 
                }
            });
        });
    };
})( jQuery );



$( "#trackMe" ).visibilityChange( function( visible ){
    $( "#status" ).css( "background-color", visible? "green":"red" ); 
} );
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try this code:

```
$(window).bind('scroll', function() {
if ($(document).scrollTop() >= $('#div1').offset().top - $(window).height()) {
    //Change css relative
}else{

}
});
```

You should play with that until you got a perfect result. Good luck

Answer (score 1):

I think you should do some tricks with window.onscroll, the window height and the heigt of div1. As in...do some code in the onscroll method...check for the window height, check for the height of div1, do some calculations on it and check if the div is out of sight...if true...remove the css.

Comment: i can try but i can't understand how to control  when scrolling up the page if div1 still getting visible again ... uhm

Comment: uhm i tthink that having the div1 height is the only solution out of there ... what you think?

Comment: If you know where the div was before scrolling down (lookng at his position in the page and the height) you must be able to determine wheter or not the div should be visible again when the page scrolls up.

Comment: onscroll attribute in html do you mean? or jquery scroll() cause the onscroll is only supported by IE

Comment: I meant the normal js function but for crossbrowser support you could use jthe Query library: http://api.jquery.com/scroll/